# Can We use SqlCacheDependency with a product not containing ASP.net part?

Tags: sql-server-2008, .net-3.5, session, sqlcachedependency

Is SQLCacheDependency used in context of ASP.net or can it be used for a project of .net only. Rather tahn using ASP.net i am receiving request by listening on a port.I want to store data for my session in cache.If this data is fetched from database then i want it to be updated using something like SQLCacheDependency.Can I configure it for my use or is it restricted for use with asp.net cache.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about SQLCacheDependency, but you might want to look at memcache.  They have some sort of built in broadcasting ability to sync cache across servers.  You might be able to do this across environments, or at least try and catch that broadcast yourself

Answer (score 0):

Use SqlDependency instead of SqlCacheDependency

http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=27881